# date handling in sqlite3 confusing.

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

I am from non database background.  I have created a table with one of the  field data type TEXT.

```
dataF TEXT
```

**INSERTION:**

Have inserted three records with the values :

```
'842-2-4'
'842-2-5'
'842-2-6'
```

**SELECTION:**

Tring to get the records based on date now.

```
... where dateF between '842-2-4' and '842-2-10'
```

It fails.

Whereas,

```
... where dateF between '842-2-4' and '842-2-8'
```

retrieves all the 3 records.

What am i doing wrong ? Why the first statment fails ?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing strings, the values are compared left to right...

As one string is shorter that the other, you are kind of comparing this...

```
'842-2-4'
'842-2-1'
```

Well, nothing is `>= '842-2-4'` AND `<= '842-2-1'`.

- *Because `'842-2-1'` comes before `'842-2-4'`.*
- *And, so, `'842-2-10'` comes before `'842-2-4'` too.*
- *Just as `'Squiggled'` comes before `'Squiggly'`*
- *And as `'xxx-y-az'` comes before `'xxx-y-z'`*

To compare as you desire, make sure all your dates are padded with `0`'s.

```
BETWEEN '0842-02-04' AND '0842-02-10'
```

But that will only work ***after*** you have padded out the values in your table too.

**EDIT**:

Also, note that this *assumes* that your format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.  As a string is compared left to right, you *must* have the highest magnitude values to the left.

*(This means that you **can't** use `YYYY-DD-MM` and still have native string comparisons behave as you would want them.)*

Comment: i tried inserting by padding '0', but still the same result :(

Comment: @Whoami - Did you correct the data in your table? Using your example you should insert `'0842-02-04'`, `'0842-02-05'` and `'0842-02-06'` and ***then*** also modify your query to use the exact same data format : `dateF BETWEEN '0842-02-04' AND '0842-02-10'`. *(Both the data in your table, and the search parameters **must** be the **exact** same format.)*

Comment: @Whoami - Please could you update your question with the following...  `1.` The CREATE statment for your table.  `2.` The INSERT statements that you are running.  `3.` The query you are using.  *[The example in this answer works on ever RDBMS I have ever used, which makes me think there is an error somewhere in those three steps.]*

Comment: Sorry.. My mistake, i forgot to add for Date/Month also. It works now. :).

Comment: do we have any function which converts to this format, without applying logic externally?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are comparing strings not dates.  The computer has no idea these are dates.  You have to either store as date and do a date comparison or implement your own logic to analyze strings.

Simply put, it is looking at the 1 in 10 as being less than your values rather than 10 being more.  It's string comparison, not date.

Although sqlite doesn't support date types, it does have functions for dealing with them.  See here:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: SQLite does not have a native date datatype.

Comment: Edited answer, see link, that should help you.

Comment: @CL.: True, but the ISO-8601 dates used in the [sqlite date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) are sortable and can be compared as strings

Comment: @HackyStack - That would require something like `DATE(table.field) BETWEEN x AND y` but that will ***destroy*** the optimiser's ability to use indexes. *(One should never wrap a search field in a function if use of indexes is desired.)* It's better to simply format the data and search parameters to allow native comparisons without inline manipulations.